# background-image not showing on Safari using JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I've tested the website that I am currently developing now on different browsers. It looks all fine until Safari misbehaves and doesn't load the `background-image` that I have coded.

The other browsers that I have tested, are working fine.

I'm thinking that maybe the code that I have used isn't compatible with Safari.
If you have any tricky way to declare a background-image using JavaScript, please teach me.

```
$("#homebtn1").click(function() {
  $("#home").css({"background-image":"url(images/New/17.jpg)","background-position":"center"});
})

$("#homebtn2").click(function() {
  $("#home").css({"background-image":"url(images/New/18.jpg)","background-position":"center"});
})

$("#homebtn3").click(function() {
  $("#home").css({"background-image":"url(images/how.jpeg)","background-position":"center"});
})
```

Sample pictures of Safari Image Error

[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]

Comment: Are you using jquery? Also the `background:` property can be set for both the position and the image and is shorter ;)

Comment: Yes sir i'm using jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the background property

```
   background-size: cover;
```

Or in jQuery

```
 "background-size":"cover",
```

That might make it work.

Hope this helps. :)